# How to get Database Connection for Octopus shard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, octopus

I am using the Octopus gem to do DB sharding in Rails.

How do I get the database connection specific to a shard. For example, I have a shard named "new_db" that I specified in my shards.yml. How do I get the db connection for it? The raw connection. I know how to update/insert to this shard, I just need the connection.

I tried the following with no avail. It just gives me the default connection I specified in my database.yml.

```
Octopus.using("new_db") do 
    connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection

end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have this behavior:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.class
#=> ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter
```

It means that your connection is not established through Octopus.

You should have:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.class
#=> Octopus::Proxy
```

instead...

---

As *momoshu* pointed out [in this GitHub issue](https://github.com/thiagopradi/octopus/issues/234), it might be caused by your app using

```
 ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
```

> I believe that if you call `establish_connection`, Octopus stops
>   proxying connections regardless of configuration in `shards.yml` or
>   `Octopus.enabled?`.

---

**Other lead**

I wasn't able to make it work because the gem was at the top of my gemfile, oddly, moving `gem 'ar-octopus'` to the bottom of the gemfile made it work.